# Enzyme Shallow not working but mount works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have the following a.jsx file which I am trying to test:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SideNavigation } from "@xxx/react-components-xxx";
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";

class Navigation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { t } = this.props;

        const ITEMS = [
            {
                type: "section",
                text: t("navigation.abc"),
                items: [
                    {
                        type: "link",
                        text: t("navigation.abc"),
                        href: "#/abc"
                    },
                    { type: "link", text: t("navigation.def"), href: "#/def" }
                ]
            }
        ];

        const HEADER = {
            href: "#/",
            text: t("navigation.title")
        };

        return (
            <SideNavigation
                header={HEADER}
                items={ITEMS}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(Navigation);
```

And following is the test case I have written:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Navigation from '../src/a';
import { SideNavigation } from '@xxx/react-components-xxx';

describe('Navigation component', () => {
    it('should render consistently', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <Navigation />
        );

        console.log(wrapper.render());
        expect(wrapper).not.toBeNull();

        const sideNav = wrapper.find(SideNavigation);
        console.log(sideNav.render());
        const sideNavProps = sideNav.props();
        console.log(sideNavProps);
    });
});
```

And with this, I get following eror:

> Method “type” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
>
> ```
>   14 |
>   15 |         const sideNav = wrapper.find(SideNavigation);
> > 16 |         console.log(sideNav.render());
>      |                             ^
>   17 |         const sideNavProps = sideNav.props();
>   18 |         console.log(sideNavProps);
>   19 |     });
>
>   at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1636:13)
>   at ShallowWrapper.type (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1372:17)
>   at ShallowWrapper.render (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1106:17)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (tst/components/Navigation.test.js:16:29)
> ```

But if I use mount instead of shallow, everything works fine here. Can someone tell what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `WithTranslation`.

They mention it in their [doc](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing)

> For testing purpose of your component you should export the pure component without extending with the withTranslation hoc and test that:
>
> ```
> export MyComponent;
> export default withTranslation('ns')(MyComponent);
> ```
>
> In the test, test the myComponent export passing a t function mock:
>
> ```
> import { MyComponent } from './myComponent';
> <MyComponent t={key => key} />
> ```

Comment: Ohh ok. Thanks for your reply. I am still facing the same error but I think now it is due to different reason, even though, I have SideNavigation as the component inside the Navigation component, but I am getting <xxx-side-navigation></xxx-side-navigation> when I am printing wrapper.html(). How can I fix this?

Comment: @hatellla `shallow` won't render sub components, use `mount` for this

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to render sub-components. But now, if I am exporting Navigation component and using shallow, shouldn't `wrapper.find(SideNavigation)` should return something? When I am doing .props on it, I am again getting: Method “type” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: @hatellla any solution you found for this issue. looks like mount is working just fine but for me too shallow returning 0 for length of component